# How do I import a SVN dump file into SourceForge?

Tags: svn, sourceforge, svndump

I currently have a project on a private SVN host which I would like to move to a SourceForge project I just created. I've exported a dump file of my current repository, and now I'm trying to load it into my new project. I found the instructions on how to do it at the bottom of [this page](https://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/sourceforge/wiki/SVN%20adminrepo), but I've never used a shell account, SSH, PUTTY or any of this stuff before so I'm a little lost.

First the instructions say to "upload the dump file to the interactive shell". How do I do this? Is there a command I'm suppose to use in PuTTY or is there a way I can just FTP the file somewhere?

Second, when I try to check out my repository using the command below I get an error "The repository lock failed."

```
adminrepo --checkout svn
```

Answer (score 0):

The sentence "upload the dump file to the interactive shell" makes no sense when referring to what you would expect as a normal shell. I never used SF but after a glance over the page you linked I'd expect this is what they mean:

The system shell.sourceforge.net appears to offer an account granting ssh access. So a) most likely it is a normal linux system and b) you probably can use the scp or sftp protocol to upload files into your home directory on that system. Then you can login using ssh and use the file. You can use putty for this, though putty is the worst ssh implementation I have ever seen.

ftp certainly is not supported. It is a protocol from the 70th. Absolutely insecure and horror for all administrators. Stop using it, switch to sftp.